# How to open previously selected date in MaterialDatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, material-components-android, material-components

- This is the code that i am using :

  ```
   val picker = builder
      .setTitleText(getText(R.string.select_start_date_and_end_date))
      .setSelection(Pair((selectedStartDate ?: calendar.timeInMillis), (selectedEndDate ?: 
       calendar.timeInMillis)))
      .setTheme(AppUtils.resolveOrThrow(requireContext(), R.attr.materialCalendarTheme))
      .setInputMode(MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR)
      .setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder)
      .build()
   picker.show(parentFragmentManager, picker.toString())
  ```
- While on click of positive button i am storing data as long value like this :

  ```
  picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
      selectedStartDate = it.first ?: 0
      selectedEndDate = it.second ?: 0
  }
  ```
- Here selectedStartDate and selectedEndDate are long variables. but calendar is not opening with previously selected dates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661948/materialdatepicker-shows-current-date-instead-of-needed

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

```
 val dateValidator: CalendarConstraints.DateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.now()
    val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    val constraintsBuilder =
        CalendarConstraints.Builder().setStart(calendar.timeInMillis)
            .setOpenAt((selectedStartDate ?: calendar.timeInMillis))
            .setValidator(dateValidator).build()

    val picker = builder
        .setTitleText(getText(R.string.select_start_date_and_end_date))
        .setSelection(
            Pair(
                (selectedStartDate ?: calendar.timeInMillis),
                (selectedEndDate ?: calendar.timeInMillis)
            )
        )
        .setTheme(AppUtils.resolveOrThrow(requireContext(), R.attr.materialCalendarTheme))
        .setInputMode(MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR)
        .setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder)
        .build()
    picker.show(parentFragmentManager, picker.toString())

    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {

        selectedStartDate = it.first ?: 0
        selectedEndDate = it.second ?: 0

        setStartAndEndDate(selectedStartDate, selectedEndDate)
    }
```

- There was a method openAt(). Thanks.